# Android Wear Styling Based on Time

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a 12-hr format watch face with AM and PM markers. I want to color the AM and PM markers different colors. The way I have been doing it was with two paints, AmPaint and PmPaint, but is there a way to do this using only 1 Paint.

```
AmPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
PmPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
```

...

```
if (amorpm.format(new Date()).equals("AM")) {
    canvas.drawText(ampm, (centerX + (time24XLength / 2.0f) - (ampmXlength / 2.0f)), time24YOffset, AmPaint);
}
else {
    canvas.drawText(ampm, (centerX + (time24XLength / 2.0f) - (ampmXlength / 2.0f)), time24YOffset, PmPaint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why not. Something like

```
if (amorpm.format(new Date()).equals("AM")) {
    canvas.drawText(ampm, (centerX + (time24XLength / 2.0f) - (ampmXlength / 2.0f)), time24YOffset, new Paint().setColor(Color.GREEN));
}
else {
    canvas.drawText(ampm, (centerX + (time24XLength / 2.0f) - (ampmXlength / 2.0f)), time24YOffset, new Paint().setColor(Color.RED));
}
```

should work.

BTW variables in Java start with lowercase.

---

Another solution based on your comment:

```
public static final Paint singlePaint = new Paint();

if (amorpm.format(new Date()).equals("AM")) {
    singlePaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
}
else {
    singlePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
}
canvas.drawText(ampm, (centerX + (time24XLength / 2.0f) - (ampmXlength / 2.0f)), time24YOffset, singlePaint);
```

Comment: I prefer to have the amPaint and pmPaint already initialized since I use it in other places

Comment: One method I was thinking of was having a boolean that returns true if new Date()).equals("AM") and having a single Paint ampmPaint